# How to setup the network under the stated conditions?

Tags: wireless-networking, network-shares, file-sharing

I have a desktop PC running `Windows 7 Home Premium`
I have a `1TB internal drive` and a `printer` attached to my PC. There is also a `320GB` master drive with OS installed in it.
I use a wireless router to provide net connection throughout the house and I am physically connected to the router.
There are other laptops in the house and I want to share my 1TB drive and the printer with them albeit with me in full control.

There is a laptop running Win7

Two laptops running WinXP

I created a `HomeGroup` network but its functionality was limited to Win7 laptop.

I want to create a network where:

Every person with a laptop has a folder in the 1TB drive but cannot access the folder of the other user

Have access to a common folder where I can keep the files which are on my PC but everyone else needs them too. Like family photos n all

Share the printer

How do I go about creating such a network? I am the admin of the house :p

Comment: This is a fairly complicated multi-issue question. This would probably be better suited being split into multiple questions. First question would be how to setup sharing in a multi-computer multi-Win-OS environment with a Win 7 comp as the server. The second would be how to set permissions on the share so that all have access to the share (share permissions to everyone) but restrict permissions for each user to his/her specific folder (folder permissions set to specific user account) and third, how to setup a shared printer.

Answer (score 1):

As for the hard drive:

You could use a VHD (Virtual Hard Drive) create the folders per user and modify permisions per folder as you like. It will be accesible as long as your computer is powered on.

Create VHD:

From your computer (not the notebooks)

- Right Click ***Computer***
- Click ***Manage***
- Click ***Disk Managment***, all availalbe drive should show
- Right click on ***Disk Managment*** and select ***Create VHD***

[image: vhd1]
Click Browse and find your drive that you want to use/share, Name the drive and click OK.
[image: vhd2]
Configure the desired amount of space you want to dedicate in total for this "network" drive.
[image]
Once the drive has been created, you may need to initialize and create simple volume / assign letter.

Now go to Computer and find your newly lettered drive (should look something like this)
[image]
Right click the drive

- Select Properties
- Select Sharing tab
- Select Advanced Shareing
- Tick the Share This Folder box

Now you can transfer and create folders in the VHD, go to the folders and set permmisions.

Comment: He would have to create users first to assign permissions right?